# Foreach weird beaviour, continue acts like break

Tags: powershell, foreach

Just noticed this weired beaviour using `ForEach-Object` (`%`), the `continue` statement, which is supposed to skip the current iteration, acts like the `break` statement and breaks the loop.

See example (should skip number 5):

```
1..10 | % {if ($_ -eq 5) {continue} else {$_}}
```

Results:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Using a `foreach` statement is working as expected:

```
foreach ($n in 1..10) {if ($n -eq 5) {continue} else {$n}}
```

Results:

```
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
10
```

Why is that? Is it a bug or does it have a purpose?